# Error al poner decimales PSEINT

Tags: pseint

He creado un programa en la aplicación de PSeInt el cual cálculo sueldo con decimales

Cuando el usuario introduce un valor como `12.324` me indica que es `menor a los 1000` euros cuando debería ser mayor.

Por que la cifra es `12 mil euros con 324 euros y no 12 euros con 324   céntimos`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Normalmente el  . en programación indica el separador de decimales. Prueba a no poner el punto.

Comment: Como @Jakala dice, estás utilizando `.` como si `12.12 = 1212` cuando no es así.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Aparte de lo que te comentan sobre el uso del punto como separador de miles (no se usa separador de miles en programación, sólo separador decimal), no entiendo porqué en el título de tu pregunta colocas *error de psicología*. No entiendo eso, ¿qué sería un *error de psicología *? Es la primera vez que escucho el término. Por otra parte, el código de tu pregunta debe ir en formato de texto y no en imagen, puedes hacer clic en [edit] para realizar los cambios necesarios. Saludos

Comment: Thanks compañeros.